# How to add alt text to tikzpicture using TeX4ht

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, accessibility

As I understand TeX4ht, for `\includegraphics` you add alt text, the kind a screen reader would find, using the alt key.

What is the recommended approach to a graphic created by `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a custom environment, that takes the alt text as an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{tikzalt}{O{} m}{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}{\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{tikzalt}[]{Hello alt}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzalt}
\end{document}
```

You can then use a TeX4ht configuration file to configure next alt text using this argument:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{tikzalt}{O{} m}{\Configure{Picture-alt}{#2}\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}{\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This code needs that you copy the newest version of [pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht/blob/master/pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def) to the directory with your document.

This is the result:

```html
<p class='noindent'>This is a test  <img alt='Hello alt' src='sample0x.svg' />
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also, this is helping me begin to understand the configure options and code.  I had found the part of the manual about Picture-alt and PictureAlt, and +, * etc., but hadn't really understood it or known how simple it was to tap into it with a command.

Comment: @EthanDuckworth that's good to hear that it works :)